# Why change window.location.href doesn't work in onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I want to redirect the current page to another page when refreshing.

I tried to do something like this. But in "console.log", the window.location.href is not changed. Why and how could I solve the problem? Thanks :-)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
  window.location.href = "google.com";
  console.log(window.location.href);
  event.returnValue = "reload?";
};
```

Comment: `To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with. Moreover, some don't display them at all.` MDN.

Comment: Browsers prevent `window.location` being changed during any `unload` event (as this would really annoy users). What are you actually wanting to accomplish?

Comment: @Dai I want to redirect the current page to another page when refreshing